# Disambiguate [connect]

Tags: discussion, tag-disambiguation

I have noticed broad misuse of the [connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/connect) tag, which is supposed to refer to "a middleware layer for Node.js".

Most of the [questions on this tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/connect?sort=newest&pageSize=50) seem to be about diverse and sundry topics including Bluetooth connect() and database connections..

Could this be renamed [node.js-connect] or something similar?

Comment: I don't think in the current state of the tag rename is actually useful as most of the questions has nothing to do with that library. Maybe you should create new tag and burniate "connect"? Or just create new tag and re-tag some of the post?

Comment: "Make the [tag:connect]ion"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since this tag only has a few correct tagged questions I support the Idea of  [Alexei's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355707/disambiguate-connect#comment508116_355707):

1. In fact we already have the tag [node.js-connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js-connect). Retag every question that is about the node middleware to this tag

If done correctly we should

2. Burninate [connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/connect) through a possible seperate request.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll try to retag the ones that deserve [tag:node.js-connect]...