# The [connect] tag is being burninated

Tags: discussion, status-planned, burninate-request

> ##### *This tag is in phase 4 of the burnination process described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070). The question and comments have been cleaned to allow for on-topic discussion about the burnination of this tag. Please keep it that way.*
>
> ###### *If you want to discuss the process of burnination itself, post a new question on Meta or visit the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570).*

---

In 2017 we had a [discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355707/disambiguate-connect) about disambiguating [connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/connect) because it was being used to mean multiple things. At the time, it was suggested to have a separate request to burninate this tag after the retagging was done.

I'm sure the 2017 retagging is done, but there's been a lot of new activity with this tag since then using it to mean lots of different things, including:

- HTTP Proxy `CONNECT`
- Mocking Python's `socket.connect()`
- [pymysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pymysql), [pyodbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyodbc), and other database connections
- [apache-kafka-connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-kafka-connect)
- [node.js-connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js-connect)
- [terraform-provider-aws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/terraform-provider-aws) (has several `connect` methods)
- [amazon-connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-connect)
- [openid-connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openid-connect)
- [twilio-twiml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twilio-twiml) `<connect>`
- Lots of other generic "connecting to something"

---

This tag meets the criteria for burnination:

- Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous? **Not well** and **no**
- Is the concept described even on-topic for the site? By itself, **no**, it is too generic.
- Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post? **No**
- Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts? **No**

This tag is actively collecting several new questions per week. I think it would be good to get rid of it sooner rather than later.

Comment: Disconnecting a connection, can cause problems, tat should be discussed and so the te tagged is as good as the connect tag

Comment: Just looking through the first page of unanswered questions, it's an absolute mess of different topics. Someone even tagged it for Adobe Connect.

Comment: Can we have a policy that ambiguous tags should not exist and when they do they are expediently removed. This thing could be avoided from the get go.

Comment: Similar to @GrahamReynolds "Mirth Connect" is a tool with its own [mirth] and [mirth-connect] tags. The [connect] tag is not appropriate for that tool https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bconnect%5D+mirth

Comment: I'm just disappointed that we're not here to "dis-[connect]," or "establishing a [connect]-shun;" the (often terrible) word-play was the best part of previous burnination notices.

Comment: @DavidThomas Puns aren't allowed in phases 2 and 4 because [reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/6296561). They're allowed before and after the burnination, but not during

Comment: @Zoe: I can't disagree with the statement, and that certainly would explain the "why," but I'm really not seeing any reasons for disallowing the puns in this phase. I followed the link you shared, and the prohibition is clearly stated but there's no rationale presented there (or in the links I've so-far followed from the linked answer). But, whatever; thank you for the information.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine We need an explicit phase #6: Pun Overflow. Where a burnination isn't considered complete until at least a few facepalm-worthy word puns have been posted.

Comment: @DavidThomas Look at the edit history to see the original title of this post.

Answer (score 15):

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- Questions about Adobe connect should use the [adobe-connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adobe-connect) tag instead.
- Questions about Mirth Connect should use [mirth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mirth) instead ([mirth-connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mirth-connect) is a synonym of [mirth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mirth) at the time of writing)
- Questions about connections to something (such as a database, website, ...) should use relevant technology tags.
- Similarly, questions about functions that happen to be called `connect` should use relevant technology tags
- Questions about Node.js' connect middleware should use [node.js-connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js-connect)
- Questions about Amazon Connect should be tagged [amazon-connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-connect)
- Questions about the OpenID Connect protocol should use [openid-connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openid-connect)
- Questions about OS-level socket implementations should be tagged [socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/socket), along with an OS tag, and optionally a tag for the socket implementation (such as [winsock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winsock) for Windows sockets)

## Progress:

The [connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/connect) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=connect),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted semi-automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bconnect%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bconnect%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bconnect%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bconnect%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## Track the progress of burnination

- <strike>[Coordination chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244740/burnination-hq)</strike> Shut down due to strike fallout.

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/connect) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance". (Edits, specially re-tags, are best left to users with [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit))

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/connect) tag—just flag/vote to close the question.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/connect) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: I've been replacing [connect] with [database-connection] for questions about connecting to a database.  Usually I'm removing [database] also, because it's usually about connecting to a specific brand of database.

Comment: Seems "Facebook connect" is a thing. The tag is just a synonym for "facebook" so the "connect" tag can safely be removed from salvageable questions, it looks like.

Comment: Can we have guidance for how to retag questions relating to general sockets and the `connect()` system call?

Comment: @DonalFellows I'll argue tagging with the relevant OS and [tag:sockets] is enough (plus optionally a presumably OS-specific tag for the socket implementation; I'm not sure what tags exist, but there's at least [tag:winsock] for the Windows socket API)