# Should the [connect] burnination resume now that the strike is over?

Tags: discussion

When the recent moderator strike... err, "action"... happened, the [connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/connect) tag [was being burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418968). However, the strike interrupted it and it was never resumed.

Should we resume it?

Comment: The mod who was coordinating the burnination attempts (Zoe) has been on hiatus since the strike. Therefore, there is nobody to watch over and deal with the remaining of the burnination. Without a mod involvement, the burninations would be an ardours process. Possible, but not as fast and as effective.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the burnination is still going; it is in phase 4, but the problem is that it isn't getting attention. Additionally, for the reasons VLAZ mentioned, it's unlikely a mod is going to get involved in the rest of it (shy of maybe editing the meta post when it's done). This mainly just means no bulk deletion, which significantly slows down the final cleanup phase.